# Cognos Lag + over partition

Tags: lag, cognos, partition-by

I am trying to recreate this in cognos:
lag(queue_name,1) respect nulls over (partition by appl_num order by seq_nmbr)

The logic works fine in terradata but cannot find a way to make this work in cognos.

Full query below for further reference:

```
SELECT
        appl_num,
        UPPER(a.user_ident) as tid,
        seq_nmbr,
        actvy_cd,
        ace_rte_to_state_que as queue_name,
        lag(queue_name,1) respect nulls over (partition by appl_num order by seq_nmbr) as lagg
    
        FROM xyz
```

Any help here would be great!!! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use SQL:

1. Create a query.
2. Add a SQL object to the query.
3. Properly configure the SQL object, including your native SQL code.

Additional details:

Cognos doesn't support `LEAD` and `LAG`.

Even if Cognos supported `LAG`:  I recently had a need of to include specific features of a window function in Cognos.  While Cognos supported the window function, it didn't support the additional features.  For example, Cognos Analytics will support...

```
MIN(Col1) OVER (
  PARTITION BY SRID 
  ORDER BY Col1, Col2
  )
```

...but not...

```
MIN(Col1) OVER (
  PARTITION BY SRID 
  ORDER BY Col1, Col2 
  ROWS BETWEEN 0 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
)
```

...in its built-in functions for the data item expressions you would create the normal Cognos way.

If you don't have the capability to use SQL objects in reports, talk to your Cognos Analytics Administrator about either providing your appropriate capabilities or them supporting the report.  Unfortunately, in order to even run a report that uses a SQL object, you must have the capability to create and edit them.  This means that even if you have the capability, your users may not be able to use the report.  (Or if the admin creates it, maybe you can't run it.)